# How can I escape the quotes for the parameter of shell script?

Tags: bash, docker, shell

I have a shell script and want to be able to pass commands like: bash -c "COMMAND ARGS"

```
set -x
cmd='bash -c "ls /lib"'
docker run --rm ubuntu:bionic $cmd
```

But I get

```
+ cmd='bash -c "ls /lib"'
+ docker run --rm ubuntu:bionic bash -c '"ls' '/lib"'
/lib": -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/lib": -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How to escape these extra quotes?

and what about if I need to get the argument from the command line, using for example ./script.sh "bash -c 'ls lib'"

```
set -x
cmd=$1
docker run --rm ubuntu:bionic $cmd
```

Comment: I don't know why you're calling `ls` on startup, but if you're looking for a file, you should be using `find` instead.

Comment: It is just an example

Comment: Why do you need Bash at all here? `docker run image ls /lib`

Answer (score 2):

Use an array, not a regular parameter, to store the command.

```
set -x
cmd=(bash -c "ls /lib")
docker run --rm ubuntu:bionic "${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: Any idea on how to get it working when passing the argument from CLI?

Comment: Why would you need the arguments to be in a variable at all? https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: I plan to make a script to run commands in a container. The commands themselves should be passed as arguments to the script